# How do I move objects in Android Studio in the graphical xml design screen?

Tags: android

I have to make a mini-project, a calculator. So I've started working on this.
When I try to place some Buttons in their place (by numerical order), there is a problem.

For example, I decided that I want 3 buttons per line.
When I try to move the upper row, all the Buttons lose their order.

Is there an auto-ordering option to I disable?

Comment: You should take a look at different layout-classes. I think a gridview is what you want to include. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html & https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html

Comment: Or a GridLayout, since some Buttons could be larger ot taller.

Comment: Use Grid layout.. it works perfectly well where you need this type of layout

Comment: Most probably you are using relativelayout, so each and every button are related to each other, one more all move. So try different layout.

Answer (score 0):

Following is a sample xml layout for 3 buttons as you said

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
        >


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Close"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Next"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Previous"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

This is simple just place them in LinearLayout horizontal it will work on All devices like:

```
<LinearLayout orientation="vertical" layout_width="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout orientation="horizontal" layout_width="wrap_content">
        <Button>One</Button>
        <Button>Two</Button>
        <Button>Three</Button>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Use as many buttons as you like.

Comment: Nested LinearLayouts? Grid or Table layout would be better

Comment: There are many ways of doing it, I like linear layout as it give me power on every button level.
Depends what suits the guy... :)

Comment: Its not nesting, it is one level layout style that works on every device from phones to tabs to web. Any way everyone has its own preferences. :)